# Multiple Hover replacements

Tags: html, css, hover

I am making an CSS button and I am focusing a problem right now.

I have following in CSS:

```
.proceed {
    width: 135px;
    height: 38px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.proceedText {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 106px;
    height: 29px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

#proceedButton {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#proceedLight {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And following into HTML:

```
            <div class="proceed">
                <a onClick="startGateway('137340');">
                    <div id="proceedButton">
                        <div id="proceedLight"></div>
                        <h1 class="proceedText">Click to Proceed</h1>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

What I want to do, when I have problem is following...

I want to make a couple of hover effects but making each element on hover doesnt give me exactly effect that I want because it will hover only when my cursor is over the "element".

I want to make hover on the .proceed to affect on all other elements. So when cursor is over ".proceed" it would do following.

```
.proceedText:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#proceedLight:hover {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Any solutions ? cause making each element on hover, doesnt really works as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to put the hover on .proceed, i think this will work.
If not try using jquery to change the dom and effects.

```
.proceed:hover  .proceedText {opacity: 0.5;}
.proceed:hover  #proceedLight{bottom: 0;}
```

Revised.
I think jquery, like the above comment, is the best solution.

Comment: Magic... did not knew about this one :] ! Shame on me.
Thank you so much, work exactly as I wanted.

*6 mins till I can accept answer!

Comment: Cool that i worked! usually use jquery for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Aham... Do you accidently have a link for that part with jquery? Just wanna check it out, who knows if I will need it sometimes.